# Using properties in Wildfly-CLI scripts for if/else Logic

Tags: jboss, wildfly

In the Wildfly CLI-scripts it is possible to test for existence of a resource and execute some conditional logic:

```
if (outcome != success) of /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=MY_DATASOURCE:read-resource  
// now do something
```

When you run the cli, you can provide properties that are available in your scripts like this:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=my.cli --properties=my.properties
```

I would like to introduce some conditional logic based on these properties to do some conditional configuration.

One example is that to configure a mail-server, sometimes the mail-server requires a username and a password and in other cases it allows anonymous access. When setting up the mail-server config i would like to be able to have conditional logic like this

```
if MAILSERVER_USERNAME is defined //confiure mailserver with username password else // configure mailserver without attributes username/password
```

The only thing that I can see that is possible is if I already have added a system-property setting to my standalone-full.xml, i can query it like this:

```
if (outcome != success) of /system-property=foo:read-resource  
 // now do something
```

I would like to do something simuilar based on the properties passed in from my.properties.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The properties you pass through `--properties` can't be used in every context, which makes testing their existence bothersome :

```
[standalone@localhost] :resolve-expression(expression=$myProperty)
Unrecognized variable myProperty
[standalone@localhost] :resolve-expression(expression=${myProperty})
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression '${myProperty}'",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

You can however solve that problem by using the `set` command in your cli script :

```
[standalone@localhost] set myProperty=${myProperty}
[standalone@localhost] :resolve-expression(expression=$myProperty)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => "myValue"
}
```

You can then use the outcome of the `resolve-expression` command to test for the existence of your property :

```
[standalone@localhost] if (outcome == success) of :resolve-expression(expression=$myProperty)
[standalone@localhost] echo success ! myProperty is set ( $myProperty )
[standalone@localhost] end-if
success ! myProperty is set ( myValue )
```

If your property isn't defined, trying to resolve it with `resolve-expression` will raise an error :

```
[standalone@localhost] set myProperty=${notMyProperty}
[standalone@localhost] :resolve-expression(expression=$myProperty)
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression '${notMyProperty}'",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Comment: The last bit is really annoying. It essentially means that you can't do anything like (if (condition) do A, else do B, based on a property passed into a script.

Comment: @stmoebius You can, it's just really bothersome. Use the `set` command for every property that might be set, then use `if (outcome == success) of :resolve-expression` to test for the existence of a value, then you can use your condition. Note that I haven't revisited this in quite some time, I wouldn't be surprised if things got better in more recent versions

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, but no, this hasn't improved (at least until Wildfly 19.1)